# Multiple regular expression interfere

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I use regex to create html tags in plain text. like this

**loop**

```
$SearchArray[] = "/\b(".preg_quote($user['name'], "/").")\b/i"; 
$ReplaceArray[] = '<a href="'.$user['url'].'">$1</a>';
```

**-**

```
$str = preg_replace($SearchArray, $ReplaceArray, $str);
```

I'm looking for a way to not match `$user['name']` in a tag.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

for 5.3+:

```
$callback = function($match) using ($user) {
    return '<a href="'.$user['url'].'">'.$match[1].'</a>';
};
$regex = "/\b(".preg_quote($user['name'], "/").")\b/i"; 
$str = preg_replace_callback($regex, $callback, $string);
```

for 5.2+:

```
$method = 'return \'<a href="'.$user['url'].'">\'.$match[1].\'</a>\';';
$callback = create_function('$match', $method);
$regex = "/\b(".preg_quote($user['name'], "/").")\b/i"; 
$str = preg_replace_callback($regex, $callback, $string);
```

Comment: I have never used a callback like this in php. i'm using php 5.2.. can i put this code in the loop and loop for 200 times?

Comment: You could...  Performance may be an issue (You might be better off with `str_ireplace()`, but you won't be able to keep the case of the name)...

Comment: i still have problems with to get a working loop in php 5.2. the error is "syntax error, unexpected '<' in on runtime-created function".

The $method and $regex are different every time. Coud you gif me a example of your code inside a loop?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that you're making several passes over the document, replacing a different user name in each pass, and you're afraid you'll unintentionally replace a name inside a tag that was created in a previous pass, right?

I would try to do all of the replacements in *one* pass, using `preg_replace_callback` as @ircmaxwell suggested, and *one* regex that can match any legal user name.  In the callback function, you look up the matched string to see if it's a real user's name.  If it is, return the generated link; if not, return the matched string for reinsertion.

Comment: What are the restrictions on user names?  Which characters are legal?  Is there a minimum or maximum length requirement?  Is there a further restriction on the first character? For example, does the name have to start with a letter?  We need that info in order to create the regex.

Comment: the regex "/\b(".preg_quote($user['name'], "/").")\b/i" works for me speed is not important. There are also other word i want to match with there own regex.

Comment: Okay, but what I'm trying to do is create a regex that will match any valid user name, and (as much as possible) *not* match anything else.

Comment: Just match the regex for that username. not anything else. And loop the regex.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to add a bunch of anchors to a document.  Have you thought of using SimpleXML.  This assumes that the anchor tags are part of a larger xhtml document.

```
//$xhtml_doc is some xhtml doc's path
$doc = simplexml_load_file($xhtml);
//NOTE: find the parent element for all these anchors (maybe with xpath)
//example: $parent = $doc->xpath('//div[@id=parent]');
foreach($user as $k => $v){
    $anchor = $doc->addChild('a', $v['name']);
    $anchor->addAttribute('href', $v['url']);
}
return $doc->asXML();
```

simpleXML helps me a lot in these situations.  It'll be a lot faster than regex, even if this isn't exactly what you want to do.